# Should questions involving competition data be allowed?

Tags: discussion

[IMO programs of different nations?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/990738/imo-programs-of-different-nations)

I asked this question at it was placed on hold. While this might have been okay, I noticed a question in the right side (Suggested questions):

[Studying for the Putnam Exam](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/305700/studying-for-the-putnam-exam?lq=1)

This question is not only open, but has 50-something upvotes.

So I think the site should take a point if view in this, should we allow or not such questions.

I am voting for yes, because they involve math competitions, an important part of maths.

Comment: Can you explain why you think competitions are an important part of mathematics? For me they are a fun way to learn more and show what I can do but not an important part of mathematics as a whole.

Comment: They form the new generations' love for mathematics. My love started from an olympiad, and most people find their talents there.

Comment: What do you mean by competition data?

Comment: Methods used, psychological factors, training programs, formats of different tests etc. Data isn't the best word, I know, please if you think there is a better word, suggest it.

Comment: I believe that methods used will be on-topic, while psychological factors and formats of different test should be off topic. By training programs, if you meant *list* of programmes offered by various agencies, that should be off topic.

Comment: I agree with psychological factors, but programmes should stay on topic.

Comment: @user2977079, may be I'm  not understanding the question properly. Can you provide a sample answer or what you expect as an answer to 'training programmes'?

Comment: For example:
"The chinese team focuses on geometry problems rather than algebra. They use book "XYZ" to do so."

Comment: Collecting rumors about practices of IMO teams is off-topic.

Comment: @user2977079: I don’t care much one way or the other about questions of this type, but I’m *very* skeptical of your claim that ‘most people find their talents there’.

Comment: I still don't really know what these competitions are or what you do in them. I am pretty sure they are highschool math?

Comment: If you can call advanced trig, combinations, generating functions, or even the IMO as math, sure. But they aren't

Comment: @WeaponofChoice Sure, rumors about the practices of IMO teams are off-topic, but in certain arenas (e.g. competition robotics) it is quite common for the best teams in the world to share resources.  If you treat the question as a reference request for resources shared by the best IMO teams in the world ("best" can be nearly objectively defined based on numeric placement, etc.) then I think it's perfectly on-topic.